# nodejs hmac md5 incorrect calculation

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl, md5, node-forge

Guys how is it possible that crypto produces the following hash

```
console.log(crypto.createHmac('md5', 'key').update('value').digest('hex'))
01433efd5f16327ea4b31144572c67f6
```

whereas node-forge produces incorrect one, however works fine for SSL calculation

```
let md5 = forge.hmac.create()
md5.start('MD5', 'key')
md5.update('value')
console.log(Buffer.from(md5.digest().data).toString('hex'))

01433ec3bd5f16327ec2a4c2b31144572c67c3b6
```

openssl produces the same output as crypto

```
echo -n "value" | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "key"
01433efd5f16327ea4b31144572c67f6
```